# Symfony2 CMF TreeBundle has disappeared

Tags: php, symfony, github, symfony-cmf

Our custom CMS utilizes `TreeBundle` from Symfony2 CMF. When deploying to a production server, `bin/vendors install` failed because apparently the whole bundle does no longer exist - at least in [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/TreeBundle). The [Symfony2 CMF homepage](http://cmf.symfony.com/) still mentions the bundle, the link just leads to a 404 page.

Is the bundle gone for good? What happened to it? Is there a Symfony 2.0 compatible replacement for it or should we just include the bundle in our own repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bundle was refactored into the TreeBrowserBundle and the old bundle removed after a while. See here for the discussion about that: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/symfony-cmf-devs/treebundle/symfony-cmf-devs/k7nm-XtXW8Q/kgZpaOJN1x8J

If you can update your project, then just do that and drop the reference to TreeBundle. Otherwise the easiest would indeed be to include it in your own repository.

We assumed that the early adopters of the CMF frequently update, and thus we removed this repository after a few months. Sorry about that. We will be more careful with backwards compatibility the more stable we get.